# Check if Object return value from API call, in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a js file with API call that return array and I have filter specific filter

API return array:
`const apiValues = ['value1', 'value2']`

```
const checkIfExist = () => {
  fetch('api/profile')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => (
          Object.values(response.apiValues).filter(value => value === 'value2');
       ); 
};

export default checkIfExist;
```

So, if API return 'value2' I need to show a component in another file:

```
import checkIfExist from './checkIfExist.js'

if(checkIfExist) {
   return (
    <SpecificChildComponent />
   );

 }
```

When I see the page, api is called but HTTP status is 404 Not Found

Comment: @Ashu I'm not sure if checkIfExist is returning the value 'value2' on the file that I'm trying to show the component.

Answer (score -1):

Your function is not returning a value. You either need to alter your function to return a promise or update it to accept a callback. Depending on your browser support/tooling you can use async/await to simplify the code.

```
async const checkIfExist = () => {
    const response = await fetch('api/profile');
    const result = response.json();
    return Object.values(response.apiValues).filter(value => value === 'value2');
};

const exists = await checkIfExist();
```

Its not clear from your example but you should not put this code into the render path of your components. Render is called many times and placing this call in render will block the whole render process every time it rerenders. You should ideally perform this call either componentDidMount or depending on your code just somewhere outside the render path.